# How do I access child xml elements?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml string saved in a legacy database that I'm attempting to parse.  I can get the string but having 2 issues getting the values that I need.  First, some sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<email>
    <meta>
        <smartForm>
            <unit name="ForgotUsername" label="Forgot Username Email">
                <textBox name="FromEmail" label="From Email" type="Email" />
                <textBox name="FromName" label="From Name" type="100" />
                <textBox name="BccEmail" label="BCC" type="EmailList" />
                <textBox name="Subject" label="Subject" type="300" />
                <textBox2 name="TextBody" label="Body" type="Memo" />
            </unit>
            <unit name="ForgotPassword" label="Forgot Password Email">
                <textBox name="FromEmail" label="From Email" type="Email" />
                <textBox name="FromName" label="From Name" type="100" />
                <textBox name="BccEmail" label="BCC" type="EmailList" />
                <textBox name="Subject" label="Subject" type="300" />
                <textBox2 name="TextBody" label="Body" type="Memo" />
            </unit>
        </smartForm>
    </meta>
    <value>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;root&gt;&lt;ForgotPassword BccEmail="test@test.com" FromEmail="test@test.com" FromName="password test" Subject="password test" TextBody="info" /&gt;&lt;ForgotUsername BccEmail="test@test.com" FromEmail="test@test.com" FromName="test" Subject="test" TextBody="test" /&gt;&lt;/root&gt;</value>
</email>
```

Issue #1 - I attempted to parse the xml using `XElement.Parse("string")` however, I cannot get the `<value>` node unless I remove the xml declaration (i.e. first 39 characters).  I'm hoping to not HAVE to do this since it's a brittle solution.

Issue #2 - Once I have the `<value>` element's contents and parsed into an XElement, I want the query to either the `<ForgotUsername>` or `<ForgotPassword>` child node of the `<root>` document element. When I got `.Elements()`, I'm told the collection is null.

What am I doing wrong?

The Value's XML after entities are replaced:

```
<root>
    <ForgotPassword BccEmail="test@test.com" FromEmail="test@test.com" FromName="password test" Subject="password test" TextBody="info" />
    <ForgotUsername BccEmail="test@test.com" FromEmail="test@test.com" FromName="test" Subject="test" TextBody="test" />
</root>
```

UPDATES:
After trying abatishchev's initial suggestion - I changed the code for issue #1 to the following:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(contentXml);
return (from element in xdoc.Elements("value")
        select element.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Based on the information provided, it should return the string in the value node; however, it's returning null.  The xdoc.Elements() (or as shown in the above snippet) return null.

Comment: Have you tried `XDocument.Parse()` instead of `XElement.Parse()`?

Comment: Tried both and same results with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `XDocument.Parse()` to create a document supporting XML declaration
- To get units, use

  ```
  XDocument.Parse("...").Root // or Element("email")
      .Elements("meta")
          .Elements("smartForm")
              .Elements("unit");
  ```
- or use XPath: `email/meta/smartForm/unit`
- also you can use query-style:

  ```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse("...");
  var q = from meta in doc.Root.Elements("meta")
          from smartForm in meta.Elements("smartForm")
          from unit in smartForm.Elements("unit")
          select unit;
  ```

Comment: After switching it to XDocument.Parse() and then calling xdoc.Elements("meta"), it says Elements() returns null.

Comment: Added snippet to main question.

Comment: @James: In brief, prepend with `XDocument.Root`

Comment: That was it.  Forgot Root.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
var xd = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");
var xv = XDocument.Parse((string)xd.Root.Element("value"));
Console.WriteLine(xv.Root.Elements().Count());
```

Output is 2, for ForgotPassword and ForgotUsername.

Answer (score 0):

For #1:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(file);
XElement valueElement = doc.Element("value");
string value = (string)valueElement;
```